# PHP/Android and JSONObject; I can only seem to access the last element

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have a set up where it is returning a possibly decent amount of info. Here is the logcat:

```
04-17 22:38:21.886: DEBUG/TestMYSQL(12603): Result of sql: 
[{"id":"1","front_text":"the dog was so cute","back_text":"its name was dolly"},
{"id":"2","front_text":"plants use the sun","back_text":"isn't that interesting"},
{"id":"3","front_text":"plants can use the sun to create","back_text":"energy"},
{"id":"4","front_text":"a plant also needs minerals","back_text":"from the soil"},
{"id":"5","front_text":"without water the plant would","back_text":"probably die"},
{"id":"6","front_text":"plants are little machines","back_text":"who love to eat"}]
```

To gain this info, I have it execute a php file. Here is some pertinent Java, android code:

```
    .....
    result = sb.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "Result of sql: " + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // parse json data
    JSONObject json_data = null;
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        }
        return json_data;
```

It turns results into a jsonObject, to which I can play with.

So here is a step before, the query part in php:

```
    include 'connectMySQL.php';

    mysql_select_db("card_db");
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$packname);

    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
        $output[]=$e;
    }
    print(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close();
```

The problem is I only seem to have access to the FINAL... eh row. That is, in the above data, I can only seem to access id:6 row.

I'm looking at the auto_complete and JSONOBJECTs but I don't have enough experience to figure this out at the moment, and it is late.

Any ideas on how to loop through the jsonObject in java?

Let me take a minute and analyze the structure for a second before turning in. I don't know much about JSON, but here is what it looks like:

I query the database with tables I've set up, blah blah.
It returns rows of data.
I suppose my question then is how does a row of key value pairs get encoded into a JSON OBJECT, and how can I access different 'rows'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the JSONObject referenced by `json_data` in each iteration of the loop. So at the end, it always returns the last element in `jArray`.

Since you need to return multiple objects, you could:

- simply return the `jArray` to the calling function. However, this means that the caller will have to deal with the details of the data transfer implementation and if you decided to change libraries or move over to XML, it'll break a lot of code and make it much harder.
- return an array or List of the actual objects that the calling code is aware of and should be dealing with. For example, you might declare a value-object (VO) that has `id, front_text, back_text` and for each JSONObject in `jArray`, you'd create a new VO and put it into an array and return that.

  ```
  public class MyVO
  {
      final public String id;
      final public String frontText;
      final public String backText;

      public MyVO(String id, String ft, String bt)
      {
          this.id = id;
          this.frontText = ft;
          this.backText = bt;
      }
  }

  List<MyVo> vos = new ArrayList<MyVO>();
  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
  for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
     json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     vos.add(new MyVO(json_data.getString("id"), json_data.getString("front_text"), json_data.getString("back_text"));
  }
  ```

  In the calling code, you could then go over the VOs:

  ```
  for(MyVO vo : vos)
  {
      //vo.id or vo.frontText or vo.backText
  }
  ```

Comment: Ahhhhh I see it now. Fantastic answer, thank you. You are a gentleman and a scholar. Or lady.